# Importing Scipy.stats through localhost throws "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error"

Tags: php, python, linux, scipy, localhost

I have a php webserver which calls a python script. Currently I haven't written any code in the python file and all it does is the following:

```
import pandas, sys
import scipy.stats
print "Hello"
```

Running the python script using php (from localhost) throws segmentation fault (core dumped). If I remove the importing of scipy.stats, the segmentation fault doesn't take place.

Your assistance in figuring out the reason for the same would be highly appreciated.

P.S: I am using linux (Ubuntu 14.04). PHP Version 5.6.23. (Apache/2.4.18 (Unix), using XAMPP )

Thanks

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Do you get a segfault when you run the script directly from python? If yes, this is not related to PHP. Otherwise provide more details on how exactly you run the script, please.

Comment: No segfault while running directly from the terminal. Using shell_exec("path/to/python /path/to/code.py");